# Condition only satisfying on the first occurance while maping array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I want to show `dollar` for *gross sales, discounts, tax, net sales*. But my below code shows dollar for only *gross sales*.

***my code***

```
tableHeadings = [
    "month",
    "orders",
    "gross_sales",
    "discounts",
    "tax",
    "net_sales",
  ]

reportData = [
{
    "orders": 119,
    "gross_sales": 21819.610000000008,
    "net_sales": 21819.610000000008,
    "discounts": 865.82,
    "tax": 0,
    "month": "October 2021"
},
{
    "orders": 7,
    "gross_sales": 4542.4,
    "net_sales": 4542.4,
    "discounts": 40,
    "tax": 0,
    "month": "September 2021"
}]
```

*table*

```js
<tbody>
  {reportData.length > 0 &&
    tableHeadings.length > 0 &&
    reportData.map((element, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        {tableHeadings.map((item, idx) => (
          <td key={idx}>
            {item === ('gross_sales' || 'discounts' || 'tax' || 'net_sales' || 'average_amount' || 'total_spent') &&
              dollar}{' '}
            {element[item]}
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>;
```

*current page look like below,*
[current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEbpL.png)

*expected behaviour*
[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRVne.png)

Comment: `'gross_sales' || 'discounts' || 'tax' || 'net_sales' || 'average_amount' || 'total_spent'` is equal to the first truthy value in the set, i.e. `'gross_sales'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its should be

```
(item === 'gross_sales' || item === 'discounts' || item === 'tax' || item === 'net_sales' || item === 'average_amount' || item === 'total_spent')
```

**What is the issue with your syntax?**

You are checking with

```
item === ('gross_sales' || 'discounts' || 'tax' || 'net_sales' || 'average_amount' || 'total_spent')
```

What this will do is it will evaluate the expression

```js
console.log('gross_sales' || 'discounts' || 'tax' || 'net_sales' || 'average_amount' || 'total_spent')
```

Its output will be `'gross_sales'` which is the first string. So your expresion work only with `'gross_sales'`. For rest all, the value will be false.

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing item === "gross_sales", either you need to seperately compare each of them

```
Ex: item === "gross_sales" || item === "discounts" etc.
```

But the best solution is to put these options in an array and then `arrayName.includes(item)`, should give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot group OR values like you did. You need to state `item` equality for every value.

```js
<tbody>
  {reportData.length > 0 &&
    tableHeadings.length > 0 &&
    reportData.map((element, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        {tableHeadings.map((item, idx) => (
          <td key={idx}>
            {(item === 'gross_sales' ||
              item === 'discounts' ||
              item === 'tax' ||
              item === 'net_sales' ||
              item === 'average_amount' ||
              item === 'total_spent') &&
              dollar}{' '}
            {element[item]}
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>;
```

What you did in that OR statement you always return `gross_sales` string.

This is because `gross_sales` is thruty and it will never go to the rest of the values. That is why you only match `'gross_sales'`

```js
console.log(('gross_sales' || 'discounts' || 'tax' || 'net_sales' || 'average_amount' || 'total_spent'))

// logs: 'gross_sales
```